# Cakephp Auth scope error message

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm using Cake's Auth component and can't seem to figure out how to set specific flash data/error message when using `scope`.

While testing by changing `active` from `0` to `1`, I can confirm the `scope` parameter works, however if `scope` returns false, I get flash data associated with my `login` method, `Your username or password was incorrect.`.

UsersController

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
    }
}
```

AppController

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array('active' => '1')
            )
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
      'controller' => 'Users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'Users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'Users',
      'action' => 'index'
    );
}
```

Is it possible to bind a specific error message for each `scope` parameter and `login` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple in CakePHP :)
You can custom error message in every method of Controller
Simple, you do it as I say ^_^

```
Exmple:
<?php
  public function accessSite(){
   //disable default message authError of Auth
   $this->Auth->authError = false; 
   $message = 'You not have permission access here';
   //set new custom message
   $this->Auth->flash($message);
  }
```